# cElementTree XML solution for R?

Tags: xml, r, large-files

In Python, it is possible to parse large XML files using a cElementTree approach.
The approach is described here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/

If I have a 450MB XML file that does not fit in memory, is there an R solution that goes through the file in chunks (e.g., following certain XML elements).  (not a scan() solution)

Comment: See this excellent answer by @Martin Morgan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643580/combine-values-in-huge-xml-files

Comment: See `?xmlEventParse` in the XML package.